# Tree Trunk Saddle Repair

Tags: tree-care

I repaired a slit tree trunk for a friend of mine. The trunk was split from the ground up 4 feet. At that point the tree had grown 5 different major branches and left a saddle in the middle where debris had gathered and had a vine growing out of it. She noticed the split after a major wind storm. I winched the branches together and got the trunk wound closed up, then drilled and bolted it 3 different directions.
My question is: What can I use to keep the debris out of the saddle to prevent foreign growth while the tree heals itself?

Comment: Can you add a photo?